# React js Map in nested array without key names

Tags: arrays, reactjs, render

i have json array like this

```
EMAIL: (3) ["john@example.com", "harry@example.com", "howard@example.com"]
FIRSTNAME: (3) ["John", "Harry", "Howard"]
LASTNAME: (3) ["Smith", "Pierce", "Paige"]
SMS: (3) ["33123456789", "33111222222", "33777888898"]
```

I am trying to create a table like this

[image]

then group of firstName , LastName and so on

in render() i have tried

```
{columnMapRows.EMAIL.map(row => (
    <TableRow >
    <TableCell align="center">{row}</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
    ))}
```

But i dont want to map with column name , i am looking for generic solution .
email , firstname , lastname are dynamic , coming form csv file , they can be changed anytime

i have also tried foreach and simple array loop . but it doesnt work
Please suggest

Comment: Are you using any specific UI library?

Comment: @Neeraj Verma what is your required output?

Comment: what you are getting in row for each EMAIL????

Answer (score 1):

You should use the index within your map function to access other data.

```
{columnMapRows.EMAIL.map((email, i) => (    
    <TableRow key={email}>
     <TableCell align="center">{email}</TableCell>
     <TableCell align="center">{columnMapRows.FIRSTNAME[i]}</TableCell>
     <TableCell align="center">{columnMapRows.LASTNAME[i]}</TableCell>
     <TableCell align="center">{columnMapRows.SMS[i]}</TableCell>
    </TableRow>
))}
// this assumes that all the array are the same length which seems to be the case
```

**EDIT:** dynamic solution assuming email is always there

```
{columnMapRows.EMAIL.map((email, i) => (    
    <TableRow key={email}>
     {Object.keys(columnMapRows).map((key) => (
        <TableCell align="center" key={key} >{columnMapRows[key][i]} </TableCell>
     ))}
    </TableRow>
))}
```

**EDIT:** dynamic solution with data refactor

```
const keys = Object.keys(columnMapRows);
const items = columnMapRows[keys[0]].map(() => ({}));
keys.forEach((key) => {
  columnMapRows[key].forEach((data, i) => {
     items[i][key] = data;
  });
});

{items.map((item) => (    
    <TableRow>
      {Object.keys(item).map((key) => (
         <TableCell key={key}>{item[key]}</TableCell>
      ))}
    </TableRow>
))}
```

This could certainly be improved but I think it shows the main idea. I decided to construct an array of object as I think it's pretty easier yo understand. Then iterate on those object properties using `Object.keys`.

Comment: email , firstname , lastname are dynamic , coming from csv file , they can be changed anytime

Comment: You mean you can have for example phone instead of sms or some data without lastname  ?

Comment: yes , instead of lastname , their can be another column like phone

Comment: its wrong , why firstname , lastname come inside email ?

Comment: in columnMapRows.EMAIL.map  ...  EMAIL want to come dynamically

Comment: I posted a full dynamic solution. Might be some typos, didn't test it.

Comment: you latest solution shows data in linear structure . not as group ... I am still trying to modifying

Comment: Ok nevermind I truly don't understand what you are trying to achieve in term of display. You are using Table items but don't want to display tabular data. A table with one column should probably be displayed in a List instead.

Comment: i changed my screenshot so you can have better understanding . your solution are useful in giving hints . but i am trying to get exact like screenshot

Comment: Then just `Object.keys(columnMapRows)` to iterate on different keys. Something like `Object.keys(columnMapRows).map((key) => (<YourComponentOutput fileHeader={key} data={columnMapRows[key]} />))`

Comment: I am close to my solution , need some more r n d . I am upvoting your solution